# Tomcat and git on ubuntu

Tags: java, git, ubuntu

I have a tomcat server on ubuntu and I have a directory where i store all my git repositories, 
how do I enable my server to accept git push via https.
I use realms to allow access to the directory.
The problem is how do I configure my server to accept git pushes.
I have looked here:[on apache](https://lightyearsoftware.com/2012/01/git-https-repository-access-control/)

how do i do the same for tomcat?
Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) - an open-source, pure Java stack for managing, viewing, and serving Git repositories

Comment: Thank you i will just one question, can i also push to my repositories using gitblit